# Execute QlikView file from task scheduler when there are no files in the folder

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, qlikview

I need to run Qlikview file (.qvw) from folder A when there is a file in folder B. How to do it? Thanks! Inna.

Comment: My advice is the you find an appropriate site, and start researching. If you choose this site for your research, you can use the search bar at the top of each page, but you cannot ask for this type of information as a question. This site helps you to fix a specific and reproducible fully explained and defined issue with your provided code. Please take the [tour], and read through [ask], and each of its linked pages, to learn more about this site.

Answer (score 0):

Your question title asks `"when there are no files in the folder"`, but your question text asks `when there is a file in folder B"`

So, we start off reading between the lines.

Then we ask what `"from folder A"` means. Perhaps the `Qlikview` executable is in `folder a`. Perhaps you mean `when "folder a" is the current directory.

And then we've no idea whether `Qlikview`needs be told the filename that was found, whether it requires the filename alone or requires the extension as well, and whether it assumes the location of `folder b`, needs to be provided with the complete path to the file, or whether the drive and directory need to be provided to `Qlikview` as separate parameters or as a full filename.

So, getting out the ol' crystal ball...

```
if [not] exist "folder b\*.qwv" for %%q in ("folder b\*.qwv") do (
 q:
 cd "folder a"
 "folder a\qlikview" {some parameters go here - qv.}
 goto done
)
:done
```

Where:
The `not` keyword, without the square brackets, is required if you wish to process according to your question title and should be omitted if you wish to process according to your question text. You should be aware, of course, that should there be no `.qwv` file in the required directory, then the following `for` will return no values and thus the entire `for` statement, up to the `do` but *not* including the `(` should be deleted. also, any filename sections that are selected are unavailable, since `%%q` will be empty.

The `q:` line is required only if you need to run with `qlikview,exe` in the current directory.
The `cd` line is required only if you need to run with `qlikview,exe` in the current directory. It does not matter whether `folder a` is specified with the drive-letter or not.
"folder a\qlikview" may have the `folder a\` omitted if the current directory is `folder a`
The variable `%%q` contains the entire name of the `*.qwv`file located - including the path `folder b`. You can pick parts of the filename by using `%%~?q` where `?` can be any combination of **D**rive **P**ath **N**ame and e**X**tension. If the filename or part-filename may contain spaces, then "enclose the selection string in quotes"
The `goto` is required if you want to process only the very first `.qwv` found in `folder b`. Omitting this line will re-invoke `Qlikview` with each `.qwv` filename found.